# Show response as html in firefox web console

Tags: laravel, firefox, firefox-addon

Once I've used firebug, but they stopped developing, and claimed, that many features where included in base firefox developers tools. So I've uninstalled the extension.

I miss one feature, where I could see my response as html. For now it's only raw or json.

Laravel produces error responses in html, it's hard to see the message in raw output.

Can someone point me, maybe extension, that adds html response feature or maybe tell me if there is an option somewhere?

Best regards!

p.s. I mean xhr response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Network response of your request in the Inspect panel

Comment: I check my response in webdeveoper tools->console, but I can see only raw response

Comment: In developer tools go to Network then find the request you called in the list of all the processes. click on the name of the request and you can see the Response or the Preview tab of it.

Comment: Btw reload your page after opening the network tab in order to see the processes.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to turn on network tab :)!, there it is. I accept your answer, but there could be html reponse mode in console, life would be easier :)

Comment: couldnt agree more :)